# The difference between fgets() and scanf()

Tags: c, user-input, scanf, fgets

This is my code. I didnt want to use `scanf()` to read the name and I tried using `fgets()` but after I put the first name and age, the second and third time my program runs the for loop it doesnt take age .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student
{
    char name[15];
    int age;
};


int main()
{
    int i;
    struct student s[A];
    for (i = 0 ; i < A ; i++)
    {
        printf("enter the names and age\n");
        fgets(s[i].name, 10, stdin);
        scanf("%d", &s[i].age);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0 ; i < A ; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t%d\n", s[i].name, s[i].age);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It doesnt work, why?

But when I replace fgets with

```
scanf("%s%d",s[i].name,&s[i].age);
```

It works fine

Comment: don't mix `gets` family with `scanf` family.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/ - RTFM

Comment: You need to explain "*How are you running the program*?"

Comment: try `scanf("%d", &s[i].age);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &s[i].age);`

Comment: give me a break guys .i am still new in c programming

Comment: thx BLUEPIXY!!    I dont understand how it works though

Comment: Prefer to read *lines*, then parse. Everything else is just asking for trouble.

Comment: `%d` of `scanf` does not consume the newline after the number.
So you need to consume it before the next `fgets`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Which is why a `fgets()` only solution is better.

Comment: @bolov That advise is rubbish.

Comment: Tell me how can `fgets` replace [scanf](http://ideone.com/ipDe5v)? There is no reason for other explanations.

Comment: [Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371391/the-difference-between-fgets-and-scanf#comment56484607_34371391) explains why code failed.  Posting example input and what you _want_ would result is good solutions.

Answer (score 2):

> The difference between fgets() and scanf()

`fgets(...)` typically reads until receiving a `'\n'`

`scanf("%d", ...)` typically:
 1. Reads and discards leading white-space.
 2. Reads numeric input (sign,digits) until scanning a non-digit.
 3. Non-digit is **put back** into `stdin` for the next input function.

---

Example:

<kbd>J</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
`"John\n"` is read by `fgets()` into `s[0].name`.

<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
`21` is read by `scanf("%d",...)` into `s[0].age`.    `'\n'` put back into `stdin`

`"\n"` is read by `fgets()` into `s[1].name`.

<kbd>M</kbd>
`"M"` is read by `scanf("%d",...)`, nothing is put in `s[1].age`.   `'M'` put back into `stdin`.

<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
`"Mary\n"` is read by `fgets()` into `s[2].name`.

<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
`19` is read by `scanf("%d",...)` into `s[2].age`.    `'\n'` put back into `stdin`

`"\n"` is read by `fgets()` into `s[3].name`.

---

Alternative: To read 2 lines, call `fgets()` twice, *then* parse:

```
int Scan_student(struct student *dest) {
  char buffer[2][80];
  dest->name[0] = '\0';
  dest->age[0] = -1;
  printf("enter the names and age\n");
  for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    if (fgets(buffer[i], sizeof buffer[i], stdin) == NULL) {
      return EOF; // stdin was closed, no more input (or input error)
    }
    buffer[i][strcspn(buffer[i], "\r\n")] = '\0'; // lop off potential trailing \n
  }
  // parse the 2 buffers: MANY options here - something simple for now.
  if (sscanf(buffer[0], " %14[-'A-Za-z ]", dest->name) != 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (sscanf(buffer[1], "%d", &dest->age) != 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}


int i;
struct student st[3];
for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(st) / sizeof(st[0]) ; i++) {
  if (Scan_student(&st[i]) != 1) break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you input both the name and the age in a single line, then that's the normal behavior because `fgets()` will read the whole line until `9` bytes (in your case) are read or a `'\n'` is found.

You need one of the two, for instance you could only use `fgets()` like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    char name[100];
    int age;
};


int main()
{
    int i;
    struct student s[1];
    for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(s) / sizeof(*s) ; i++)
    {
        char number[100];
        char *unconverted;
        printf("Name > ");
        fgets(s[i].name, sizeof(s[i].name), stdin);
        if ((unconverted = strchr(s[i].name, '\n')) != NULL)
            *unconverted = '\0'; // Remove the trailing '\n'
        printf("Age  > ");
        fgets(number, sizeof(number), stdin);
        s[i].age = strtol(number, &unconverted, 10);
        if ((*unconverted != '\0') && (*unconverted != '\n'))
            s[i].age = -1; // Invalid value indicating input error
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(s) / sizeof(*s) ; i++)
        printf("Name: %s\nAge : %d\n", s[i].name, s[i].age);
    return 0;
}
```

Or `scanf()` only

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    char name[100];
    int age;
};


int main()
{
    int i;
    struct student s[1];
    for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(s) / sizeof(*s) ; i++)
    {
        printf("Name Age > ");
        if (scanf("%99s%d", s[i].name, &s[i].age) != 2)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "input error\n");
            s[i].name[0] = '\0';
            s[i].age = -1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(s) / sizeof(*s) ; i++)
        printf("Name: %s\nAge : %d\n", s[i].name, s[i].age);
    return 0;
}
```

and you can then input both name and age in a single line.

The `fgets()` method is better because you don't need to deal with the `'\n'` that `scanf()` doesn't pick up from `stdin`. A combination would work if you are careful to force the user to input the values in separate lines.

Comment: But sometime for the same reason you need to remove `'\n'` because of `fgets`. We cannot compare them at all. And `scanf` is all most always wrong used.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest fgets() isn't required here as you've specified to read from stdin you should simply use gets() this reads from stdin by default. If your moving between a scanf() statement and a gets() statement you should use fflush(stdin) to clear out the input stream, example below:

```
scanf("%99s", s[i].name);
fflush(stdin);
gets(s[i].age);
```

In general your better sticking with either scanf() or gets() and not combining them.

Comment: gets is deprecated and shouldn't used anymore.

Comment: In C11, `gets()` is not longer available with the standard library.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up guys! I didn't realize that.

Comment: Also, `fflush(stdin)` is not defined by the standard. The `fflush()` function is only defined for output streams. You need to manually deal with `scanf()` and remove the trailing `'\n'` from `stdin`. It's very hard to write useful code with `scanf()` no matter your skills and effort.